# Why is there an extra blank line after using gsub on file in Ruby with Thor?

Tags: ruby, regex, thor

I have some Ruby code that processes a Gemfile.  It adds some recommended gems and removes other gems.  There's a section of a Gemfile that looks like the following:

```
group :development, :test do
  # The gem version is a recommended starting place; upgrade if needed.
  gem 'pry-rails', '~> 0.3.4'
  # Enhance pry with byebug (which gives more debugger commands and other goodies).
  # The gem version is a recommended starting place; upgrade if needed.
  gem 'pry-byebug', '~> 3.4.0'
  # Use rspec for testing
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.5.1'
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: mri
end
```

I'm using the following two lines to remove the last two lines of the block (the `gem 'byebug ...` line and the comment above it).

```
gsub_file(full_app_gemfile_path, /^\s*gem\s*("|')byebug.*$/, "", verbose: false)
gsub_file(full_app_gemfile_path, /^\s*#.*Call.*("|')byebug("|').*$/, "", verbose: false)
```

The `gsub_file` is a method provided by the `Thor` gem.   The removal works, but I end up with the following code in the Gemfile

```
group :development, :test do

  # The gem version is a recommended starting place; upgrade if needed.
  gem 'pry-rails', '~> 0.3.4'
  # Enhance pry with byebug (which gives more debugger commands and other goodies).
  # The gem version is a recommended starting place; upgrade if needed.
  gem 'pry-byebug', '~> 3.4.0'
  # Use rspec for testing
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.5.1'
end
```

Why is that extra blank line being inserted after `group :development, :test do`?  It's nowhere near where the lines were removed.  It could possibly be a bug in the Thor gem, but I'm wondering if it's regex issue.

**Update**

I just tried using the raw ruby gsub (to eliminate potential Thor issues). I created a helper method

```
def my_gsub(path, regex, str)
  text = File.read(path)
  rep = text.gsub(regex, str)
  File.open(path, "w") {|file| file.puts rep}
end
```

When I change the two lines that are calling `gsub_file` to call `my_gsub`, I now get two blank lines after `group :development, :test do`.

Comment: Looks like a Thor bug. Could you check which of the two `gsub`s adds the line?

Comment: I just updated the text.  I created a helper method to call the Ruby `gsub` command directly so Thor can be eliminated from the troubleshooting.  Now I'm getting two blank lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your method `my_gsub` you are replacing the content of the line without replacing the linebreak. To make it remove the newline as well you can change your regex to this:

```
gsub_file(full_app_gemfile_path, /^\s*gem\s*("|')byebug.*$\n/, "")
gsub_file(full_app_gemfile_path, /^\s*#.*Call.*("|')byebug("|').*$\n/, "")
```

Comment: This does not explain why the lines appear after `group :development, :test do`, while the `byebug` definition is in the end.

Comment: When I ran the code, it did appear at the end of the block, so I assumed that was the problem, with the code in the question there will be no newline  in the beginning of the block with ruby 2.3.3

Comment: Thank you.  This solved the problem (although I'm still curious as to why the line appeared several lines up).